# Alternative 'differential' map on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Given $a, b: I \to M$, smooth curves on some manifold M, $a(0) = b(0) = p$ and $a'(0) = b'(0) = 0$. Prove that the map $D_p: \mathcal{F}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $D_p(f) = (f\circ a)''(0)-(f\circ b)''(0)$ is linear and satisfies Leibniz rule. Find the corresponding vector in coordinates. 
It have a couple of similar exercises, that is why I would like to have a proof of this as an example.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I don't understand what to do. I mean I tried to calculate $D_p(f+g)$, but I do not even understand what $((f+g)\circ a)''$ is. That is why I would like to see an example, so I can solve the rest of them by myself.

Comment: @Limsup It might be good to add the reference for this exercise.

Comment: It might be instructive to consider the case $M=\mathbb{R}^2, p=0, a:t\mapsto (t^2,0), b:t\mapsto (0,t^2)$.